# Django, persistance without serialization

Tags: python, django, sane

I'm working on a Django project that uses a flatbed scanner. It takes a long time to connect to the scanner. So I'm looking for a way to re-use the scanner instance.

Serialization seems to be the go to solution for this problem. Unfortunately I can not serialize or pickle the scanner instance. I keep running into errors that tell me that that serialization failed.

Is there an alternative way to re-use the same scanner instance for multiple scans? A back-end trick or maybe some front-end magic? (Note, I know nothing about front-end development.)

**We can cheat a little!**

The project will be running offline on a local computer, there is no internet or network connection at all. This might give options that are otherwise insecure.

**Stuff I'm using for scanning**

- [sane](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane), packages for accessing scanners
- [python3-sane](https://python-sane.readthedocs.io/en/latest), a Python wrapper for sane
- [Image Scan](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.html), drivers for scanners

Comment: Write a service that is connected to the scanner, and connect to this service from your django app. That way the service process can keep the scanner connection opened between requests.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have found info on how to run a python script as a service. But I'm having a hard time finding info on how to interact with that service, I have no idea how to do that. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, writing a service requires much more than just "run a python script as a service", indeed - you have to define the communication protocol, API etc, and well, only you know what would be the most appropriate for your project and context.  What you're looking for is "inter process communication".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I found a solution with RPyC, thanks for the tip! Would have never toughed about running a service.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for a bit I found [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). The tutorial provides a working example, I got it running in a couple of minutes.

The service starts and connects to the scanner. Multiple clients can call the service and scan immediately.

```
import rpyc
import sane


class MyService(rpyc.Service):

    def __init__(self):
        self.scanner = Scanner()

    def on_connect(self, conn):
        pass

    def on_disconnect(self, conn):
        pass

    def exposed_scan_image(self):
        self.scanner.low_dpi_scan('scanner_service')


class Scanner(object):
    """
    The Scanner class is used to interact with flatbed scanners.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        sane.init()
        self.device_name = None
        self.error_message = None
        self.device = self.get_device()

    def get_device(self):
        """
        Return the first detected scanner and set the name.

        @return: sane.SaneDev
        """
        devices = sane.get_devices()
        print('Available devices:', devices)

        # Empty list means no scanner is connect or the connected scanner is
        # already being used
        if not devices:
            self.error_message = 'Scanner disconnect or already being used.'
            print(self.error_message)
            return None

        # open the first scanner you see
        try:
            device = sane.open(devices[0][0])
        except Exception as e:
            self.error_message = e
            print(e)
            return None

        brand = devices[0][1]
        model = devices[0][2]
        self.device_name = "{brand}_{model}".format(
            brand=brand,
            model=model
        )

        print("Connected to:", self.device_name)

        # set to color scanning mode, this is not always the default mode
        device.mode = 'color'

        return device

    def low_dpi_scan(self, file_name):
        """
        Scan at 300 dpi and store as jpeg.

        @param file_name: string
        """
        image = self.scan_image(300)
        image.save(file_name+'.jpeg')

    def scan_image(self, dpi):
        """
        Scan an image.

        @param dpi: integer
        @return: image file
        """
        self.device.resolution = dpi
        self.device.start()
        image = self.device.snap()

        return image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    t = ThreadedServer(MyService(), port=18861)
    t.start()
```